# Extracting the first day of month of a datetime type column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime64

I have the following dataframe:

```
user_id    purchase_date 
  1        2015-01-23 14:05:21
  2        2015-02-05 05:07:30
  3        2015-02-18 17:08:51
  4        2015-03-21 17:07:30
  5        2015-03-11 18:32:56
  6        2015-03-03 11:02:30
```

and `purchase_date` is a `datetime64[ns]` column. I need to add a new column `df[month]` that contains first day of the month of the purchase date:

```
df['month']
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-02-01
2015-03-01
2015-03-01
2015-03-01
```

I'm looking for something like `DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date, "%Y-%m-01") m` in SQL. I have tried the following code:

```
     df['month']=df['purchase_date'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(day=1))
```

It works somehow but returns: `2015-01-01 14:05:21`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Simpliest and fastest is convert to `numpy array` by [`to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) and then cast:

```
df['month'] = df['purchase_date'].to_numpy().astype('datetime64[M]')
print (df)
   user_id       purchase_date      month
0        1 2015-01-23 14:05:21 2015-01-01
1        2 2015-02-05 05:07:30 2015-02-01
2        3 2015-02-18 17:08:51 2015-02-01
3        4 2015-03-21 17:07:30 2015-03-01
4        5 2015-03-11 18:32:56 2015-03-01
5        6 2015-03-03 11:02:30 2015-03-01
```

Another solution with [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and `pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)` and add `pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)` for correct ouput if first day of month:

```
df['month'] = (df['purchase_date'].dt.floor('d') + 
                           pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1))
print (df)
   user_id       purchase_date      month
0        1 2015-01-23 14:05:21 2015-01-01
1        2 2015-02-05 05:07:30 2015-02-01
2        3 2015-02-18 17:08:51 2015-02-01
3        4 2015-03-21 17:07:30 2015-03-01
4        5 2015-03-11 18:32:56 2015-03-01
5        6 2015-03-03 11:02:30 2015-03-01
```

---

```
df['month'] = ((df['purchase_date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1))
                         .dt.floor('d'))
print (df)
   user_id       purchase_date      month
0        1 2015-01-23 14:05:21 2015-01-01
1        2 2015-02-05 05:07:30 2015-02-01
2        3 2015-02-18 17:08:51 2015-02-01
3        4 2015-03-21 17:07:30 2015-03-01
4        5 2015-03-11 18:32:56 2015-03-01
5        6 2015-03-03 11:02:30 2015-03-01
```

Last solution is create `month period` by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['month'] = df['purchase_date'].dt.to_period('M')
print (df)
   user_id       purchase_date   month
0        1 2015-01-23 14:05:21 2015-01
1        2 2015-02-05 05:07:30 2015-02
2        3 2015-02-18 17:08:51 2015-02
3        4 2015-03-21 17:07:30 2015-03
4        5 2015-03-11 18:32:56 2015-03
5        6 2015-03-03 11:02:30 2015-03
```

... and then to `datetimes` by [`to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html), but it is a bit slowier:

```
df['month'] = df['purchase_date'].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
print (df)
   user_id       purchase_date      month
0        1 2015-01-23 14:05:21 2015-01-01
1        2 2015-02-05 05:07:30 2015-02-01
2        3 2015-02-18 17:08:51 2015-02-01
3        4 2015-03-21 17:07:30 2015-03-01
4        5 2015-03-11 18:32:56 2015-03-01
5        6 2015-03-03 11:02:30 2015-03-01
```

There are many solutions, so:

**Timings** (in pandas 1.2.3):

```
rng = pd.date_range('1980-04-01 15:41:12', periods=100000, freq='20H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'purchase_date': rng})  
print (df.head())



In [70]: %timeit df['purchase_date'].to_numpy().astype('datetime64[M]')
8.6 ms ± 27.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [71]: %timeit df['purchase_date'].dt.floor('d') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)
23 ms ± 130 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [72]: %timeit (df['purchase_date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)).dt.floor('d')
23.6 ms ± 97.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [73]: %timeit df['purchase_date'].dt.to_period('M')
9.25 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [74]: %timeit df['purchase_date'].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
17.6 ms ± 485 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


In [76]: %timeit df['purchase_date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(normalize=True)
23.1 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [77]: %timeit df['purchase_date'].dt.normalize().map(MonthBegin().rollback)
1.66 s ± 7.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: The problem with `pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)` is when purchase_date is the first day of the month, your code will return the first day of the previous month.

Comment: @pomber - Try use `pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0)`

Comment: `pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0)` works for the first day but fails for the rest

Comment: I agree, the solution is flawed for when the date is the first day of the month.

Comment: How is the answer even accepted - it's just flawed and it completely ignores the corner cases (first or the last day the month, depending on parameters of `MonthBegin`) @jezrael, please exted your example with `2015-01-01` and `2015-01-31` to see the problem

Comment: Great answer! Realised without converting to numpy also works for the first code snippet: `df['month'] = df['purchase_date'].astype('datetime64[M]')` (pandas v1.3.5)

Comment: @ZolzayaLuvsandorj this also works for pandas v1.0.3

Comment: offsetting MonthBegin will go to the next beginning of a month, meaning if you are already at the beginning of the month you will offset to the beginning of last month. The docs suggest using pd.offsets.MonthBegin().rollback(ts) to find the start of the current month.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin.html

Comment: @PaulMartin - Thanks, but it not working with Series like `pd.offsets.MonthBegin().rollback(df['purchase_date']) `

Comment: @jezrael in this case, you would use apply to the series, eg
`df['month'] = df['purchase_date'].apply(lambda date: pd.offsets.MonthBegin().rollback(date))`

Comment: @PaulMartin - It is not vectorized, so I try avoid it - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code/54432584#54432584)

Answer (score 13):

We can use [date offset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) in conjunction with [Series.dt.normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
In [60]: df['month'] = df['purchase_date'].dt.normalize() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
   user_id       purchase_date      month
0        1 2015-01-23 14:05:21 2015-01-01
1        2 2015-02-05 05:07:30 2015-02-01
2        3 2015-02-18 17:08:51 2015-02-01
3        4 2015-03-21 17:07:30 2015-03-01
4        5 2015-03-11 18:32:56 2015-03-01
5        6 2015-03-03 11:02:30 2015-03-01
```

Or [much nicer solution from @BradSolomon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304531/extracting-the-first-day-of-month-of-a-datetime-type-column-in-pandas/45304722?noredirect=1#comment77573703_45304722)

```
In [95]: df['month'] = df['purchase_date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1, normalize=True)

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
   user_id       purchase_date      month
0        1 2015-01-23 14:05:21 2015-01-01
1        2 2015-02-05 05:07:30 2015-02-01
2        3 2015-02-18 17:08:51 2015-02-01
3        4 2015-03-21 17:07:30 2015-03-01
4        5 2015-03-11 18:32:56 2015-03-01
5        6 2015-03-03 11:02:30 2015-03-01
```

Comment: Or pass `normalize` as param, `df.purchase_date - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1, normalize=True))`.

Comment: @BradSolomon, wow! Thank you! I didn't know `pd.offsets.MonthBegin()` has such a parameter

Comment: @MaxU If `df['purchase_date']` is already on the first day of a month, minus `MonthBegin(1)` would return the first day of the previous month.

Comment: What should happen if the purchase_date is already the first day of the month? For `2017-08-01 03:45:56` I'm getting: `2017-07-01`

Answer (score 11):

How about this easy solution?
As `purchase_date` is already in `datetime64[ns]` format, you can use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) to format the date to always have the first day of month.

```
df['date'] = df['purchase_date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-01'))

print(df)
 user_id   purchase_date       date
0   1   2015-01-23 14:05:21 2015-01-01
1   2   2015-02-05 05:07:30 2015-02-01
2   3   2015-02-18 17:08:51 2015-02-01
3   4   2015-03-21 17:07:30 2015-03-01
4   5   2015-03-11 18:32:56 2015-03-01
5   6   2015-03-03 11:02:30 2015-03-01
```

Because we used `strftime`, now the `date` column is in `object` (string) type:

```
print(df.dtypes)
user_id                   int64
purchase_date    datetime64[ns]
date                     object
dtype: object
```

Now if you want it to be in `datetime64[ns]`, just use [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

print(df.dtypes)
user_id                   int64
purchase_date    datetime64[ns]
date             datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 10):

Most proposed solutions don't work for the first day of the month.

Following solution works for any day of the month:

```py
df['month'] = df['purchase_date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(normalize=True)
```

[EDIT]

Another, more readable, solution is:

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin
df['month'] = df['purchase_date'].dt.normalize().map(MonthBegin().rollback)
```

Be aware not to use:

```py
df['month'] = df['purchase_date'].map(MonthBegin(normalize=True).rollback)
```

because that gives incorrect results for the first day due to a bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32616

Comment: This also works for last day of month `pd.to_datetime('2021-01-31')+pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(0)-pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin() == Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00')`

Answer (score 6):

Try this ..

```
df['month']=pd.to_datetime(df.purchase_date.astype(str).str[0:7]+'-01')

Out[187]: 
   user_id        purchase_date       month
0        1  2015-01-23 14:05:21  2015-01-01
1        2  2015-02-05 05:07:30  2015-02-01
2        3  2015-02-18 17:08:51  2015-02-01
3        4  2015-03-21 17:07:30  2015-03-01
4        5  2015-03-11 18:32:56  2015-03-01
5        6  2015-03-03 11:02:30  2015-03-01
```

Comment: Simplest that doesn't involve another library (like numpy)

Answer (score 3):

To extract the first day of every month, you could write a little helper function **that will also work if the provided date is already the first of month**. The function looks like this:

```py
def first_of_month(date):
    return date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(-1) + pd.offsets.Day(1)
```

You can `apply` this function on `pd.Series`:

```py
df['month'] = df['purchase_date'].apply(first_of_month)
```

With that you will get the `month` column as a `Timestamp`. If you need a specific format, you might convert it with the `strftime()` method.

```py
df['month_str'] = df['month'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: This worked great, even for the first day of the month. I vectorized it though instead of doing the `.apply()` like so: 
`df['date_flat'] = df['date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(-1) + pd.offsets.Day(1)`

Answer (score 2):

For me `df['purchase_date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)` didn't work (it fails for the first day of the month), so I'm subtracting the days of the month like this:

```
df['purchase_date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['purchase_date'].dt.day - 1, unit='d')
```

Comment: While this is the only solution that works for the first day of the month, it's much slower than using MonthBegin for some reason, were you able to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

@Eyal: This is what I did to get the first day of the month using `pd.offsets.MonthBegin` and handle the scenario where day is already first day of month.

```
import datetime

from_date= pd.to_datetime('2018-12-01')

from_date = from_date - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1, normalize=True) if not from_date.is_month_start else from_date

from_date
```

result: `Timestamp('2018-12-01 00:00:00')`

```
from_date= pd.to_datetime('2018-12-05')

from_date = from_date - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1, normalize=True) if not rom_date.is_month_start else from_date

from_date
```

result: `Timestamp('2018-12-01 00:00:00')`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my 2 cents, for the sake of completeness:

1 - transform purchase_date to date, instead of datetime. This will remove hour, minute, second, etc...

```
df['purchase_date'] = df['purchase_date'].dt.date
```

2 - apply the datetime replace, to use day 1 instead of the original:

```
df['purchase_date_begin'] = df['purchase_date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))
```

This replace method is available on the datetime library:

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
month_start = today.replace(day=1)
```

and you can replace day, month, year, etc...

Answer (score -1):

try this Pandas libraries, where 'purchase_date' is date parameter placed into the module.

```
date['month_start'] = pd.to_datetime(sched_slim.purchase_date)
.dt.to_period('M')
.dt.to_timestamp()
```

Comment: Not bad solution but this code won't run as is. Need brackets around the code after =