# Check if a date lies in first half of month or second in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which consists of a date column but the date column is in string.
How can I check if the date lies in first half of the month or the second half and add add another column with the billing date

For e.g.

if the date is `08-10-2020`(format is dd-mm-yyyy) then the `billing date` column will consist of 16th of the same month and if the date lies in between 17-31 it then the billing date will consist of 1st day of next month

Data:

```
print(df['dispatch_date'].head())

0    01-10-2020
1    07-10-2020
2    17-10-2020
3    16-10-2020
4    09-10-2020
Name: dispatch_date, dtype: object
```

example output:

```
                 billing date
0    01-10-2020  16-10-2020
1    07-10-2020  16-10-2020
2    17-10-2020  01-11-2020
3    16-10-2020  01-11-2020
4    09-10-2020  16-10-2020
```

Comment: Can you fix index 3, first its 15-10-2020, than 16-10-2020 and shouldnt that lie in the first half of the month?

Comment: `dt.ceil('SM')` would be nice (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html), but it doesn't seem to work. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using `apply` as follows-

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

dates = ['01-10-2020', '07-10-2020', '17-10-2020', '15-12-2020', '19-12-2020']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dates, columns=['dates'])

# if the billing data can still be string going ahead
print(df.dates.apply(lambda x: '16'+x[2:] if int(x[:2]) < 16 else '01-'+str(int(x[3:5])+1)+x[5:] if int(x[3:5]) != 12 else '01-'+'01-'+str(int(x[6:])+1)))
df['billing_date'] = df.dates.apply(lambda x: '16'+x[2:] if int(x[:2]) < 16 else '01-'+str(int(x[3:5])+1)+x[5:] if int(x[3:5]) != 12 else '01-'+'01-'+str(int(x[6:])+1))

# if billing date series is needed as a datetime object
print(df.dates.apply(lambda x: dt.date(int(x[-4:]), int(x[3:5]), 16) if int(x[:2]) < 16 else dt.date(int(x[-4:]), int(x[3:5])+1, 1) if int(x[3:5]) != 12 else dt.date(int(x[-4:])+1, 1, 1)))
df['billing_date'] = df.dates.apply(lambda x: dt.date(int(x[-4:]), int(x[3:5]), 16) if int(x[:2]) < 16 else dt.date(int(x[-4:]), int(x[3:5])+1, 1) if int(x[3:5]) != 12 else dt.date(int(x[-4:])+1, 1, 1))
```

Output

```
0    16-10-2020
1    16-10-2020
2    01-11-2020
3    16-12-2020
4    01-01-2021
Name: dates, dtype: object

0    2020-10-16
1    2020-10-16
2    2020-11-01
3    2020-12-16
4    2021-01-01
Name: dates, dtype: object
```

Edit: code handles the edge case scenario possible in december

Comment: By this logic I am getting `billing_date` as `01-13-2020` . How can I change that ?

Answer (score 1):

**Pure pandas, no string or apply modifications needed:**

- locate all dates with days before the 16th and set them to the 1st of monthst of that month plus semi month end (wich is the 15th)
- locate all other dates dats on or after 16th and move it to the begin of next month

We need two different `df.loc`'s because

```
df['billday'] = df['date'].dt.floor('d') + pd.offsets.SemiMonthEnd()
```

would move the dates to 15th and the (28th to 31th depending on month and leap year) of that month unfortunately.

---

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date 

# create demo data    
dt = [date(2020,10,i) for i in range(1,32,3)]    
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dt})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
print(df)


# create billday colums     
df.loc[df.date.dt.day < 16, "billday"] = df['date'].dt.floor('d') +\
                                             pd.offsets.SemiMonthEnd() # to 15th
df.loc[df.date.dt.day > 15, "billday"] = df['date'].dt.floor('d') +\
                                             pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
 
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         date    billday
0  2020-10-01 2020-10-15
1  2020-10-04 2020-10-15
2  2020-10-07 2020-10-15
3  2020-10-10 2020-10-15
4  2020-10-13 2020-10-15
5  2020-10-16 2020-11-01
6  2020-10-19 2020-11-01
7  2020-10-22 2020-11-01
8  2020-10-25 2020-11-01
9  2020-10-28 2020-11-01
10 2020-10-31 2020-11-01
```

---

See:

- [pandas.Series.dt.floor.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)
- [pandas.offsets.SemiMonthEnd](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/offset_frequency.html?highlight=offsets#semimonthend)
- [Conditional Replace Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas)
- [Extracting the first day of month of a datetime type column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304531/extracting-the-first-day-of-month-of-a-datetime-type-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-11', periods=10, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng})

df['Billing'] = df["Date"].map(lambda ts: pd.to_datetime('{:}-{:}-{:}'.format(ts.year, ts.month if ts.day < 16 else ts.month + 1, 16 if ts.day < 16 else 1)))

print(df)
```

So the end result would be:

```
        Date    Billing
0 2015-02-11 2015-02-16
1 2015-02-12 2015-02-16
2 2015-02-13 2015-02-16
3 2015-02-14 2015-02-16
4 2015-02-15 2015-02-16
5 2015-02-16 2015-03-01
6 2015-02-17 2015-03-01
7 2015-02-18 2015-03-01
8 2015-02-19 2015-03-01
9 2015-02-20 2015-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def bill(x):
    res=''
    d, m, y=x[:2], x[3:5], x[6:]
    if m!='12':
        resd, resm, resy =('16', m, y) if int(d) in range(1,16) else ('01', str(int(m)+1), y)
    else:
        resd, resm, resy =('16', m, y) if int(d) in range(1,16) else ('01', '01', str(int(y)+1))
    if len(m)==1:
        resm='0'+ resm
    return resd + '-' + resm + '-' + resy

df['billing_date']=df['dispatch_date'].apply(bill)
```

Result:

```
  dispatch_date billing_date
0    01-10-2020  16-10-2020
1    07-10-2020  16-10-2020
2    17-10-2020  01-11-2020
3    16-10-2020  01-11-2020
4    09-12-2020  01-01-2021
```